# Constructing a direction of unboundedness of a linear program

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

I think if a linear program is unbounded, there is a direction of unboundedness.

Consider a linear program,

$$\min \{ cx \mid Ax = d, x \geq 0\}$$

Given that the linear program is feasible and unbounded, I want to explicitly construct a direction of unboundedness $y$ such that

1. $cy < 0$
2. $Ay = 0, y \geq 0$.

I have tried to use the difference of two feasible solutions $x' - x$ such that $x' \geq x$ as a direction. However, this is implicitly using a direction of unboundedness. What are other ways to construct a direction of unboundedness?

Comment: Note that finding this direction would be equivalent to solving 
$$
\min\{cy \mid Ay = 0, 1^Ty = 1, y \geq 0\}
$$
where $1^T$ denotes the row-vector $(1,\dots,1)$. I don't believe that is explicitly solveable.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thanks for the comment. That's right since the extreme directions are the extreme points of the set $\{Ay = 0, 1^T y = 1, y \geq 0 \}$. I think unbounded LP guarantees the existence of an extreme direction. Is there a way to show that $cy < 0$ (which I think should be)?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question. I think you're trying to ask "is there a way to show that if $\min \{\ cx| Ax = d, x \geq 0\}$ is unbounded and $y$ is a direction of unboundedness, then $cy < 0$". Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, $y$ also satisfies that $Ay = 0, 1^Ty = 1, y \geq 0$.

Comment: Ok, so now I understand your question to be "is there a way to show that if $\min \{\ cx| Ax = d, x \geq 0\}$ is unbounded, then $\min\{cy \mid Ay = 0, 1^Ty = 1, y \geq 0\} < 0$." Is that correct?

Comment: I don't have to put the direction into a form of linear programming. So my question should be formed as "If min $\{cx| Ax = d, x \geq 0 \}$ is unbounded, then can I show the existence of $y$ such that $cy < 0, Ay = 0, 1^Ty=1, y \geq 0$."

Comment: Okay, but this is equivalent nevertheless. If there exists a $y$ satisfying the constraints for which $cy < 0$, then the minimum of $cy$ for such $y$ is less than $0$ and vice versa. In any case, now things are clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I claim that if $\{cx \mid Ax = d, x \geq 0\}$ is non-empty and without lower bound, then $\{cx \mid Ax = 0, x \geq 0\}$ (which is necessarily non-empty) must be without lower bound.

In particular, because $\{cx \mid Ax = d, x \geq 0\}$ has no lower bound, weak duality implies that the dual optimization problem
$$
\max\{d^Tz \mid A^Tz \leq c^T\}
$$
must be completely infeasible. That is, $A^Tz \geq c^T$ has no solutions. But this implies that the optimization problem
$$
\max\{0^Tz \mid A^Tz \leq c^T \}
$$
is also infeasible. Strong duality implies that this could only occur if the corresponding primal problem, $\min\{cx \mid Ax = 0, x \geq 0\}$, is feasible without lower bound.

It immediately follows that there exists a $x' \in\{x \mid Ax = 0, x \geq 0\}$ with $cx' < 0$. Taking $y = \frac{x'}{\|x'\|_1} = \frac{x'}{1^Tx'}$ gives us the desired "direction of unboundedness".

---

An alternative proof for the existence of such a $y$:

We note that $\{cx \mid Ax = d, x \geq 0\}$ is unbounded below, and the the feasible set $F = \{x \mid Ax = d, x \geq 0\}$ is convex. Let $x_0 \in F$.
For any $k < cx_0$, there exists an $x$ with $cx \le k$. By convexity and linearity, we see that $x_0 + t\frac{x - x_0}{\|x - x_0\|_1} \in F$ for $0 \le t \le \|x - x_0\|_1$. Moreover, since $cx < k$, we have
$$
cx_0 - k = c(x_0 - x) \le \|c\|_\infty \|x_0 - x\|_1 \implies \|x - x_0\|_1 \ge \frac{cx_0 - k}{\|c\|_\infty}.
$$
Now, for any $n \in \Bbb N$, define
$$
C_n = \left\{\frac{x - x_0}{\|x - x_0\|_1} \mid cx \le -n\right\}.
$$
The sets $C_1,C_2,\dots$ form a nested sequence of compact subsets of $\{x:Ax = 0\}$. It follows that their intersection $C = \bigcap_{n \in \Bbb N}C_n$ is non-empty.

Thus, there exists a $y$ for which $\|y\|_1 = 1$, $x_0 + ty \in F$ for all $t \geq 0$, and $c(x_0 + ty)$ is decreasing over $t$.

To argue that $y \geq 0$, it suffices to note that if this were not the case, then it would be impossible to have $x_0 + ty \in F \subset \{x:x \geq 0\}$ for all $t \geq 0$.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you! Only one edition would be the constraints of the dual problem should be $A^Tz \leq c^T$ (which doesn't affect the problem that I am solving). I have tried to make the edition, but the site doesn't let me since the edition is too little. Probably you can make the edition.

Comment: @lovemath Fixed it, thanks